# Evolute of Viviani's Curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Can anyone explain to me why the evolute of Viviani's Curve is a single point. I'm afraid I don't understand why that is.

Comment: How are evolutes when not in a plane defined? For an evolute to be a point, it should be a circle or the like, please check the problem.

Comment: @Narasimhan Evolutes can be defined in space, see the interesting chapter (in particular paragraph 8.4) : http://webmath2.unito.it/paginepersonali/sergio.console/CurveSuperfici/AG8.pdf A specific property of Viviani's curve (following its defintion) is that it lies on a sphere.